# Whats causing all these errors in knockout code?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've been trying different way to achieve the following task, where a user can add a Proposal with a collection/array of hotels. (not using arraymap or "with:" databind)

```js
function Proposal() {
    var self = this;
    self.details = ko.observable("");
    self.makmazarat = ko.observable("");
    self.medmazarat = ko.observable("");
    self.fee = ko.observable("");
    self.hotelproposal = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.addhotel = function (hotel) {
        self.hotelproposal.push({
            hotelname: "",
            checkin: "",
            checkout: "",
            roomtype: "",
            viewtype: ""
        });
    }
}

function hotel() {
    this.hotelname = ko.observable();
    this.checkin = ko.observable();
    this.checkout = ko.observable();
    this.roomtype = ko.observable();
    this.viewtype = ko.observable();
}



ko.applyBindings(new Proposal());
```

This is my html:

```
   <h2>Contacts</h2>

<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Details</th>
            <th>fee</th>
            <th>MakMazarat</th>
            <th>MedMazarat</th>
            <th>Hotels</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input data-bind='value: details' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input data-bind='value: makmazarat' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input data-bind='value: medmazarat' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input data-bind='value: fee' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.hotelproposal">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input data-bind='value: hotelname' />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input data-bind='value: checkin' />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input data-bind='value: checkout' />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input data-bind='value: roomtype' />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input data-bind='value: viewtype' />
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table> <a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.addhotel'>Add hotel</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<textarea data-bind='value: lastSavedJson' rows='5' cols='60' disabled='disabled'></textarea>
```

Even though on jsfiddle i am getting a single error, but on the console, i'm getting 68 errors. It says something about not using "proposals" which i don't understand. whats the error?

jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/Lq0b2nfc/

Comment: _"It says something"_ What _precisely_ is the error?  And a link to your jsfiddle may be beneficial.

Comment: `with: info`, but you don't have a property named `info` on your view-model

Comment: The error I see when I run your code is *"Unable to process binding "with: function (){return info }" Message: info is not defined*

Comment: Not related to your initial errors, but your `addhotel` method should probably push a `new hotel()` rather than the object literal so that its properties are observable.

Comment: @JamesThorpe so from what you are saying the code should be something like:
self.addhotel = function (hotel) {
        self.hotelproposal.push(new hotel())
            }

Comment: Your example after your edit is still binding to something that doesn't exist in your viewmodel (`lastSavedJson`) and your jsfiddle has even more bindings to properties that don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you're not doing is using your Hotel constructor (I capitalized it, since it's customary for constructors to be capitalized). You also left out a "removePhone" function, which you had bound in your fiddle though you removed that from your code above.

```js
function Hotel() {
  this.hotelname = ko.observable();
  this.checkin = ko.observable();
  this.checkout = ko.observable();
  this.roomtype = ko.observable();
  this.viewtype = ko.observable();
}

function Proposal() {
  var self = this;
  self.details = ko.observable("");
  self.makmazarat = ko.observable("");
  self.medmazarat = ko.observable("");
  self.fee = ko.observable("");
  self.hotelproposal = ko.observableArray([]);

  self.addhotel = function(hotel) {
    self.hotelproposal.push(new Hotel());
  }

  self.removePhone = function(hotel) {
    self.hotelproposal.remove(hotel);
  }
}


ko.applyBindings(new Proposal());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<h2>Contacts</h2>

<div id='contactsList'>
  <table class='contactsEditor'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Details</th>
        <th>fee</th>
        <th>MakMazarat</th>
        <th>MedMazarat</th>
        <th>Hotels</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.hotelproposal">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input data-bind='value: hotelname' />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input data-bind='value: checkin' />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input data-bind='value: checkout' />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input data-bind='value: roomtype' />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input data-bind='value: viewtype' />
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removePhone'>Delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.addhotel'>Add hotel</a>
</div>
```